# Wordpress: Woocommerce - How do I display the proceed to checkout button only when the minimum amount is reached?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am experiencing an issue, I don't want the checkout button until and unless the minimum amount for the sale has been met. In this case I don't want the total amount to be less that 250. I will post my code below, I would really be grateful if I can get this to work.

**CODE:**

```
if($postcode_present && wc_cart_totals_order_total_html() >= 250){
    $checkout_url = WC()->cart->get_checkout_url();
    echo '  <a href="'. $checkout_url .'" class="checkout-button button alt wc-forward">Proceed to Checkout</a> ';  
}
```

This is my attempt for the above issue but it isn't working.

**UPDATE:**
I will post the function of the total order:

```
function wc_cart_totals_order_total_html() {
$value = '<strong>' . WC()->cart->get_total() . '</strong> ';
```

Comment: can you `echo $postcode_present." ".wc_cart_totals_order_total_html();` before the `if` and let us know what you see?

Comment: `165.00 1` This is the output I got

Answer (score 1):

According to what each of the values hold (from your comment), you could try one of the 3 scenarios below:

```
//min sale 250
if($postcode_present >= 250){
    $checkout_url = WC()->cart->get_checkout_url();
    echo '  <a href="'. $checkout_url .'" class="checkout-button button alt wc-forward">Proceed to Checkout</a> ';  
}
else 
{
    echo 'You must at least buy 250';  
}


//min sale 1 product
if( wc_cart_totals_order_total_html() >= 1 ){
    $checkout_url = WC()->cart->get_checkout_url();
    echo '  <a href="'. $checkout_url .'" class="checkout-button button alt wc-forward">Proceed to Checkout</a> ';  
}
else 
{
    echo 'You must at least buy 1';  
}

//min sale 1 product and 250 worth
if($postcode_present >= 250 && wc_cart_totals_order_total_html() >= 1)
{
    $checkout_url = WC()->cart->get_checkout_url();
    echo '  <a href="'. $checkout_url .'" class="checkout-button button alt wc-forward">Proceed to Checkout</a> ';  
}
else 
{
    echo 'You must at least buy 250 and min 1 product';  
}
```

also, using WooCommerce, you could enjoy some of the plugins that do this for you, like [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/minimum-purchase-for-woocommerce/) or [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/shopp-minimum-order-amount/).

Comment: `$postcode_present` is a boolean value I believe, that is to check if the postcode is present.

Comment: it can't be, why did it echo `165.00` then? Also, look at the 2 links I just added.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the help and the links Sina I will test them out. I don't know why the price is being echoed before the postcode. Also I do believe that happened as the Value of the total is a String as it contains **Rs.** in it.

Comment: No worries mate, please let us know what approach worked for you, and choose an answer if it solved your problem :)

Comment: Sure thing, are the links free or lite versions with change of upgrade?

Comment: One of them is free, though I believe both of them should provide you with some good features with no costs :)

Comment: I used the Minimum Purchase for WooCommerce, it is a lite version, did the job but checkout option is still available

Comment: Mate you could **easily** do that bit via jQuery.

Comment: Ok, I'm not all that experienced with jQuery